# What happens if user aborted by php process exiting browser in the middle?

Tags: php, security, process

While PHP Settings of ignore_user_abort is set to False by default, 
Assuming i have the following code:

```
1  1ms   $user->giveMoney(500) 
2  2ms   $user->sendNotification("You got 500")
3  1ms   $user->takeCoins(200)
```

What if the user aborted the browser after exactly 3ms ? would line 3 be executed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it will, seeing as the code you've posted doesn't seem to be producing any output, and you're asking about the behavior in a client-server context. As mentioned [in the docs](http://www.php.net/ignore_user_abort):

> When running PHP as a ***command line script***, and the script's ***tty*** goes away without the script being terminated then the script will die the next time it tries to write anything, unless value is set to `TRUE`

I've highlighted some key words: this setting deals with PHP when it's being used for *command line scripts*. You mention a client, closing his/her browser. There's no TTY, so this setting can be `false` or `true`, it won't change a thing.

In your case, though, the man states that:

> PHP will not detect that the user has aborted the connection until an attempt is made to send information to the client. Simply using an `echo` statement does not guarantee that information is sent, see `flush()`.

That is to say: the script will keep on running until actual output is *really* sent to the client. Only then can PHP determine whether or not the connection to the client is still alive. If it isn't *then* your script will halt.

So unless there is some actual output being sent in that second line of code, and any output buffers are flushed, then yes, the third line will execute. If output is sent, then the script will probably halt.
But if you really want to prevent that third statement from being executed in case of a lost connection, then perhaps call [`connection_aborted`](http://www.php.net/connection_aborted) after the second method returns:

```
$user->sendNotification("You got 500");
if (connection_aborted())
    exit(0);//no error code, just exit
$user->takeCoins(200);
```

Comment: ignore_user_abort() can also be used on the server. That line is about "**WHEN** running PHP as a command line script".

Comment: @Qualcuno: Was typing up a substantial edit. You're right: it's not CLI specific, so I've edited my response accordingly

Comment: What you state in your edit is correct. However, at times it's not easy to know for sure when the server will flush the output to the client. Thus, it can still be a good idea to add `ignore_user_abort(1)` for being certain.

Comment: @Qualcuno: adding `ignore_user_abort(1)` won't help if you want the script to abort if the user disconnects, though. For that, you'll have to `flush` all buffers, use `connection_status()` and what have you, and _pray_ that it picks up on a lost connection quite quickly (if that's what you really need)

Comment: PHP can flush its buffers at times, even without you telling it to.

Comment: @Qualcuno: Yes, but that wouldn't be a problem. If it flushes the buffers, then it'll pick up on a lost connection. If you `echo`, but the buffers aren't flushed, that's when you won't notice a the disconnect. For that reason, the second quote in my answer ends with _"see `flush()`"_

Answer (score 1):

You can control that behaviour with http://php.net/manual/en/misc.configuration.php#ini.ignore-user-abort

At the configuration level (e.g. on a .htaccess file) you can set the flag:

```
php_flag ignore_user_abort 1
```

At the script level (valid for that script only) you can call this function:

```
ignore_user_abort(1)
```

**NOTE**: The documentation is a bit misleading. `ignore_user_abort` works ALSO on the server. See also [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2183262/192024) for more references.